# Powershell extracting logs based upon interval?

Tags: powershell, csv, scripting

I have script logic as follows:-

- check if the folder is empty
- If **yes** Use the same command with exception time period of last 30 days. i.e StartDate etc
- If folder not empty get / extract the logs for 1 day using same command
  just tweaking timesettings.
- the script will be scheduled to run every 5 minutes. For every run extract using the same command for 1 day saves the result in temp.csv and compare it most updated copy of final-admin.csv.
- If changes found; write difference / over-write in
  final-admin.csv

**code**

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010
$outcsv='c:\Mail-audit-results\Final-mail-admin.csv'
if(Get-ChildItem C:\Mail-audit-results){

    $enddate=[datetime]::Today
    $Startdate=$enddate.AddDays(-1)
    $splat=@{
         Identity='mail.test-nw.com'
         LogonTypes=@('Admin','Delegate')
         ShowDetails=$true
         StartDate=$Startdate
         EndDate=$enddate
    } 

        Search-MailboxAuditLog @splat | Export-Csv c:\Mail-audit-results\temp_results.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
        $Old = Import-CSV $outcsv
        $New = Import-CSV c:\Mail-audit-results\temp_results.csv
        $New | ?{$Old -notmatch $_} | Export-CSV $outcsv -notype    
    }

    #process items when files found
}else{
    # process when no files found.
    $enddate=[datetime]::Today
    $Startdate=$enddate.AddDays(-30)
    $splat=@{
         Identity='mail.test-nw.com'
         LogonTypes=@('Admin','Delegate')
         ShowDetails=$true
         StartDate=$Startdate
         EndDate=$enddate
    } 
    Search-MailboxAuditLog @splat | Export-Csv $outcsv -NoTypeInformation -Append


}

    Get-ChildItem 'c:\Mail-audit-results\Final-mail-admin.csv' | ForEach {


    Else 
    { 
    return 0;



    }

}
```

**Problem-points**

How can I change the format of date in mm/dd/yyy format in section

```
$enddate=[datetime]::Today
$Startdate=$enddate.AddDays(-1)
```

How to overwrite with difference data?

```
$New | ?{$Old -notmatch $_} | Export-CSV $outcsv -notype
```

I don't want to write to third file the difference I want original file `$outcsv` to get written; would the above command overwrite/ or just append?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your dates using *-Uformat* switch

```
$enddate= Get-Date ([datetime]::Today) -UFormat "%m%d%Y"
$Startdate= Get-Date ($enddate.AddDays(-1))  -UFormat "%m%d%Y"
```

The line

`$New | ?{$Old -notmatch $_} | Export-CSV $outcsv -notype`

will overwrite data, *Export-CSV -Append*  will append.